# How to determine the aggregation type of a measure field in a Power BI custom visual

Tags: powerbi-custom-visuals

I am using a measure field in my custom visual and want to display its aggregated value. However, when inspecting the dataview object, I noticed that the aggregates are always minLocal and maxLocal, and the queryName is always set to "Sum(...)" even when the user has selected a different aggregation type like average.

Here's a screenshot of the dataview object for reference:

[image]

Here is measure from capabilities.json file:

```
{
      "name": "primaryMeasure",
      "kind": "Measure",
      "displayName": "Measure",
      "description": "Primary measure",
      "requiredTypes": [
        {
          "numeric": true
        }
      ]
    },
```

and I want to display the aggregated value of the measure in my visual. But in the dataview, the aggregates are always minLocal and maxLocal. even the queryName is always `Sum(`..., even if I select average:

I also added this as issue in GitHub/PowerBI-visuals-tools:

[How to determine the aggregation type of a measure field in a Power BI custom visual](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-tools/issues/461)

I want to know if there's a way to programmatically determine the aggregation value for the measure field without relying on assumptions based on the displayName.